# Stream closed by us: Timed out waiting for stream resumption (connection-timeout) smack+ejabbered presence

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm using smack 4.2.0 with eJabbered for presence management 
 
everything works well but after a while, available users become unavailable.

if I'm trying to get the presence from the roster the presence is correct (availble)

I get this in the stanza message:

`<presence to=‘XXXX’ from=‘XXXX’ type=‘unavailable’><status xml:lang=‘en’>Stream closed by us: Timed out waiting for stream resumption (connection-timeout)</status></presence>`

I've searched a lot but didn't find anything on this.

Thank you for giving your time

Comment: it seems TCP/IP connection getting lost. enable mod_ping on ejabberd server and also set stream resume_timeout and resend_on_timeout: true.

Comment: This post may help you:
[Ejabberd with stream management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803743/ejabberd-with-stream-management-xep-198-not-using-offline-message-hook).